# Inbound traffic is not working via public IP of server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, nat

I have two servers in a private network in our VPC, both have public IPs and private(10.0.0.0/24) subnet.

1. Server 1 is configured to be NAT (ubuntu 18.04)
2. Server 1 has only following configuration and nothing else i.e `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 && iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
3. Server 2 is just a simple server which should use NAT server (Server 1) for outgoing traffic.
4. Both servers use `ens10` interface for private networking and `eth0`for public IP

I have enabled the following networking configurations and route on `Server 2` to route outgoing traffic via `Server 1`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.x #public-ip
  netmask 32

#Private network interface
auto ens10
iface ens10 inet dhcp
   post-up ip route add default via 10.0.0.1
```

Outgoing traffic works as expected as I can reach the internet with no issues and I see the NAT IP instead of Server 2's public IP.

But when I try to connect to server 2 using its public IP i.e for SSH or for accessing other ports it does not reply back. Although I can reach Server 2 only via the local network.

Apart from that as soon as I remove the route `post-up IP route add default via 10.0.0.1` I can reach from to the `Server 2` via its public IP but all outgoing traffic routes to the primary interface as well, which I don't want.

It seems like when packets hit to eth0 on Server 2 they are getting routed to ens10 gateway 10.0.0.1 and maybe that is why I can't regt reply if I have the route that I mentioned above.

Please point me in the right direction, I am kind of stuck at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "split tunnel":

Add the following rules under `eth0` interface configuration

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address x.x.x.x
  netmask 32
  post-up ip rule add iif lo from x.x.x.x table 123
  post-up ip route add y.y.y.y dev eth0 table 123
  post-up ip route add default via y.y.y.y table 123
```

(y.y.y.y is the gateway address)

With the above rule and route table (replying) traffics originate from the host itself with the public address as the source address will go out via eth0.

Note: After adding the configurations you might need to restart the entire server as just restarting network services might fail.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but when run the second command I get following error
`Error: either "to" is duplicate, or "123" is a garbage.`

Comment: I missed `table` in the second line; corrected.

Comment: This worked like a charm, I have a suggestion to edit the answer. Adding these rules with post-up command under th eth0 for persistant change. You saved my life thanks

Comment: Please review and accept my suggestions I will approve your answer.

Comment: No problem. Done.

Comment: Hey Tom sorry to disturb you again, this setup works in general but now I have one more problem, when I try to access services running within the server 2 I can't access them. It seems they reply back on the wrong interface, I guess.
I have following subnet configured for docker and if I use your configurations for plublic interface than even if I am on the server I can't reach them.  
10.42.0.0/16

Comment: `within the server 2` what exactly do you mean by that? the rule doesn't affect localhost/loopback access, as the local table takes precedence (see priority `0` in `ip rule`). accessing from its docker container would be another story i suppose. you probably need to have route to its subnet configured anyway. you can have it in the main table i suppose. it's not related to the original problem anyway, unless i am missing something. (for the record, i have no experience with docker at all, so i don't really know how the containers interconnect with their host)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I answer to myself. The openvpn server pushes redirect-gateway. I added "route-nopull" in the client options to limit the traffic using the VPN table.
Explanations here:
[Ignoring redirect-gateway](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IgnoreRedirectGateway?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=2917b02f016375231275ee12338b02c84c797d78-1587823320-0-AUM-Wu7FKzQjCZIxn3nIQTgAMbkeQNNbyr66MfRi4uTuFeVyss_XI1Vh2v-eFX7fFhv05dz6z8bGbQ0nZiVh62hfxosaX5XOl99tzraCMJ7Yq73w_W2pOqB-eKkcWcAm-kK4pIc_RD5yMNBIxf-tfUPjtH8qpYyVmasWzGPbNNOFw6OaiwgTtxoVSt9KDUwcZWgCYW1cLrljZ0vQl_QvAIH3-gi_vhX3iDpvlCOHL9VhLnh7Seip5ssxUpm0mPTxfhFe3oqlwxEbFiIlnb5wEjwa-aRkshjoDDS06HnzxqkS3jTBzFKxsteQoBBpzeNSiQ)

Comment: Eric I think you answered on the wrong question.